# highest security: encode password before or after transmission?

Tags: security

Premises:
1- user starts client program, enters identification
2- client program sends identification to server over ssl connection
3- server validates identification and allows or not access

Scenario 1:
- reputable 1way transform library is used on password on client machine before transmission

Scenario 2:
- password is sent over connection and is transformed by same library on server machine

Question:
 Which scenario is the safest from a security consideration, transforming the password on the client machine before transmission or on the server machine after transmission?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but based on what I think you're asking, I'd think encoding data *before* it goes over the wire would be the safest way.

Comment: Hummm, i mean it's an ssl connection either way, i'm just wondering if the credentials (password), which are going to be stored on the server after being hashed/salted, if that transormation is better done on the client machine or on the server machine, with all else being equal.

Comment: Never transmit a reusable secret. The transmission might be protected (SSL) but the server can be compromised. It is even worse if you store the password in clear form, even for a short period of time. In your case there is absolutely no reason to take the less secure path. Note: if the hash is constant you still have a security problem. A challenge-response protocol would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL connection protects the password from eavesdroppers.

no need to hash the password on the client, moreover if you did, it would only make the hash itself be the password.

So the right place to do proper hashing is on the server.

BTW:

- only STORE hashed passwords
- use a random salt for every password
- use a SLOW HASH even a perfectly good fast hash is NOT suitable to store passwords.